# Create deep copy of _ENV and change values without changing originals

Tags: lua, sandbox

I am working on some Lua code where it can sandbox function calls with as custom environment. I need to create a copy of _ENV, modify functions in it, and run a function using the new environment. So far I have this:

```lua
new_env = _ENV

function newIoOpen(f,m)
  print("Function is opening file "..f)
  return io.open(f,m)
end

new_env.io.open = newIoOpen

function testFunction()
  io.open("bar.txt","r") -- should print: "Function is opening file bar.txt"
end

io.open("foo.txt","r") -- should stay silent

setfenv(testFunction,new_env)
testFunction()
```

Instead, the regular io.open call prints "Function is opening file foo.txt" and calls itself again. Same thing with the function's io.open. When I replace the function of the new environment, it edits the old one. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How could `_ENV` and `setfenv` coexist in the same program?  They are from different Lua versions.

Comment: Replace `new_env = _ENV` with `new_env = setmetatable({}, {__index=_ENV})`